# Integrating SendGrid’s SMTP API with CFMAIL

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, sendgrid, cfmail

I am using [SendGrid’s SMTP API](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/index.html) (not WEB API) and am considering sending an email using `cfmail`. If I use `cfmail` to send the email, and want to use the `X-SMTPAPI` header somewhere, do you think that `cfmail` is a place to do that? Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do this by adding a custom header, using the `cfmailparam` tag. As such:

```
<cfmailparam  
    name="X-SMTPAPI" 
    value="{\"category\":\"Cool Emails\"}">
```

In context of the `cfmail` tag it would be as follows.

```
<cfmail 
    from="you@example.com" 
    to="nick@sendgrid.com" 
    subject="I am using CF Mail to do this!"> 
<cfmailparam  
    name="X-SMTPAPI" 
    value="{\"category\":\"Cool Emails\"}">

Look at my awesome use of cfmail!
</cfmail>
```

[More can be found in the Adobe Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c15.html)

Comment: Thanks. By anychance you know where do I need to mention the following changes mentioned here:

    1)Change your SMTP username and password to your SendGrid credentials
    2)Set the server host name to smtp.sendgrid.net
    3)Use ports 25 or 587 for plain/TLS connections and port 465 for SSL connections

 http://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/index.html

Coldfusion Server? since I am using it?

Comment: If you want every e-mail you send via CF to go through Sendgrid's servers, you can set it in the CF Admin (Server Settings > Mail). Otherwise, `cfmail` supports designating the server, username/password, and port via the `server`, `username`, `password`, and `port` attributes (http://cfdocs.org/cfmail).

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.
The above suggestion threw errors.

```
<cfmailparam  
    name="X-SMTPAPI" 
    value='{"category":["Cool Emails"]}'>
```